# Quick one about cookie expirey

Tags: jquery, cookies

I've created a cookie on a locally stored file using the jquery plugin. When I refresh the page I can see evidence of my cookie but when I close the browser and open the page again there is no evidence of my cookie and I have to restart again even though I have set the cookie to expire in 7 days like this:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#button').click(function(){
    var toAdd = $('input[name=homeworkIn]').val();
    $('.listOutput').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');
    $.cookie('test_cookie', toAdd, {expire: 7});


});
```

});

Is there something wrong with the expirey in my code? Or will this expirey not work unless the page is not a local file?

Answer (score 1):

Its `expires` not `expire`, so try:

```
$.cookie('test_cookie', toAdd, {expires: 7});
```

See **Usage** [here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)